# Camel SMPP consumer route not working properly with dynamic creation

Tags: spring, apache-camel, smpp

I am trying to receive DELIVER_SM from the smsc. The first snippet of code where the smpp route is created statically, works just fine. But later, I wanted to listen to more than one smpp routes which are dynamically created with credentials returned from a SQL query so I wrote the second snippet which I thought it would run fine but instead, the route doesn't get to the printPdus method where i can see the DELIVER_SM. The snippet doesn't work because it is not starting with smpp as a consumer from a "from uri="smpp://...""? How could I make something like this but with dynamically created smpp routes using spring.

```
<route id="Report-route">
  <from uri="smpp://${pdus.systemid}@${pdus.address}:${pdus.port}?password=${pdus.password}" />
  <to uri="bean:SmsReceiver?method=printPdus" />
</route>


<route id="Report-route">
  <from uri="sql:{{sql.selectReceivingRoutes}}" />
  <to uri="bean:SmsReceiver?method=createReceivingRoutes" />
  <recipientList>
    <header>receiverRoutes</header>
  </recipientList>
  <to uri="bean:SmsReceiver?method=printPdus" />
</route>
```

Comment: Also posted the same question to Apache Camel mailing list at: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-SMPP-consumer-route-not-working-properly-with-dynamic-creation-tp5738587.html